# General info about ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I'm evaluating ASP.NET Boilerplate as a basis for a few new projects. I'd like to know which are exactly the differences beetween .NET and .NET Core versions, and which would suit better for long-term projects.

For example:

- In some point of documentation are reported some differences beetween two versions (for example custom data filters are available just for EF 6.x): is there a complete list of differences or a comparison table?
- I've downloaded both samples (.NET/AngularJS & .NET Core/Angular) and saw some differences beetween db structure: .NET Core version has some more tables (AbpEntityChanges, AbpEntityChangeSets, ...): why db templates are different? Does .NET version lack of some functionality?
- Is it possibile to have a template with .NET and Angular instead of AngularJS? Or is possibile to use Angular App template for .NET Core with .NET version of ABP template?

Comment: It's not .NET/AngularJS. It's MVC5/AngularJS. Definitely go ASP.NETCore/Angular. You can choose .NET46/Angular or .NETCore/Angular.

Comment: I would prefer Core. it's trending. new features come to AspNet Core. Even Microsoft suggests that.